# what are issues involved allocating and initializing subclass of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

    cell.firstLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
    cell.secondLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", NUMBER_OF_ROWS - indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

this is code snippet from Apple [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

`MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];` is working fine and need no checking against nil because the cell is defined in story board and alway return valid cell.

But if I am not using story board, programmatically how I will use multiple custom cells in my tableview? And what are issues involved `allocating and initializing MyTableViewCell`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use methods

```
- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
- (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

of UITableView. You can read documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

When you called method

```
- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

, it checks if there is available cell in reuse queue. If not, it checks if it can create this cell automatically. If you have register cell class or nib for this reuse identifier before, it will create new cell using class or nib and return it. If you haven't register anything, it will return nil.

It is better to use registering, because, if you have different custom cells for different reuse identifiers, code for creating these cells becomes messy. Also it's the right way. Methods for registering were added in iOS5 and iOS6 respectively. Code for creating custom cell by programmer is related to old versions of iOS.

Comment: please can you tell in bit detail how these method works and why not alloc init subclass of uitableviewcell, and how you find these methods :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own custom cell in this way also

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    MyTableViewCell *cell=(MyTableViewCell *)[self.yourtableview  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:0];//change as per your need

   if(cell==nil)
    {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell=self.mytableviewcellref;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=@"sometext";
    return cell;
}
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: @ SJ. you need to load Nib while using custom cell.

Comment: Please tell me why you did not alloc init subclass of uitableviewcell and how this loadNibNamed works?

Comment: you are connecting the custom cell directly at its cell.xib to your view controller. So you can just load its Nib here. If you are using default UITableViewCell then you must alloc to use it if it is nil..@SJ..

Comment: I have subclass of uitableviewcell and it has nib also, I want to create 5 different kind of cells, should I create 5 different subclass of uitableviewcell?

Comment: You need to create 5 different xibs to your custom cell and load them using 
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil]; ///change MYTableViewCell as per xib name. for each indexpath

Answer (score 1):

If you want create cell programatically then you need to allocate and initialised table cell like this.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
static NSString *identifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [listtableview dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell ==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }
}
```

Comment: I am using custom cell MyTableViewCell, not just a regular cell.

Comment: ok no problem :) in this case you have to make a saprate class of Custom cell please check this link here you can find how can we add custom cell  http://mrmaksimize.com/ios/Custom-UITableViewCell-With-NIB/

Comment: I want to do all programmatically, no NIB or storyboard.

Comment: ok then in case you should add your cell element(label, image) programatically in custom cell class. check this for more detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969355/how-to-create-a-custom-uitableviewcell-programmatically-using-autolayout

Comment: check also http://jslim.net/blog/2013/03/22/ios-create-uitableview-with-custom-cell-programmatically/ :D

Answer (score 0):

There is another method which you can use:

```
MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"> forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

You pass additional parameter - indexPath.
After that check if cell is nil and if so you allocate and initialise it.

Comment: I see no allocation and initialization of MyTableViewCell. How it will work?

Comment: You check if it's nil and it so you allocate and initialise it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a storyboard, then you need to check the cell against nil and if so, allocate a new cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[MyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.firstLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
    cell.secondLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", NUMBER_OF_ROWS - indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```