# Custom table cell not resizing to fit content view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm implementing a table view with 3 types of custom cells. As shown below, in the company information section, the headquarters label for my custom table view cell `CompanyInfoTableViewCell` is getting cut off because I think the custom table cell is not resizing to fit the content view.

[image]

I tried implementing this below code in the `viewDidLoad` method of the controller containing the table view. This code was suppose to make the cells automatically resize to fit the content, but it didn't work (**Edit:** It didn't work because I'm making the custom cells and table view ***PROGRAMMATICALLY USING NO STORYBOARD***). How do I get my custom table view cell to show all my content?

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.setNeedsLayout()
self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

**`CompanyInfoTableViewCell` Code:**

```
class CompanyInfoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {        
        //Create industry label
        industryLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: horOffset, y: 0, width: 0.8*screenSize.width, height: 21))
        industryLabel.center.y = 15
        contentView.addSubview(industryLabel)

        
         //Create headquarters label
        hqLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: horOffset, y: 0, width: 0.8*screenSize.width, height: 21))
        hqLabel.center.y = 40
        contentView.addSubview(hqLabel)
                
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Comment: Please add bottom constraint to your view in storyboard as the estimated row height would not work without it. This is a common issue when your constraints are not working.

Comment: I'm trying to do this programmatically, I don't have a storyboard

Comment: you can always add bottom constraint programmatically

Comment: Go with this link, how to give  [Constraints programatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html) and [UITAbleviewCell constraints programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969355/how-to-create-a-custom-uitableviewcell-programmatically-using-autolayout)

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy the second link you provided gives an answer in objective c, do you have an answer in swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using the storyboard and AutoLayout constraints then you need to manually calculate the height which the `UILabels` are going to take based on the content it holds. I don't see any code which calculates the height based on content and accordingly setting the height of your labels and also the height of your custom cell.

You must implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to set the height for your cells.

Comment: `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` This two methods do the same as `heightForRowAtIndexPath` do.

Comment: No, both are same but there is difference in the performance like `.rowHeight`is the property and `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is the delegate method that means if cell is generated then  each time delegate method will be called.

Comment: You are wrong, check https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html

Comment: Read again this document and check this [Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells)